# Ruby: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I am working on some simple ruby exercises and cannot figure out why I am getting the "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end". I keep running over my code and don't see what is wrong, although I am new to ruby.

```
def SimpleSymbols(str)

    spec_char = "+="
    alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    str.each_char do |i|
        if spec_char.include? i
            next
        else alpha.include? i 
            if spec_char.include? str[str.index(i) + 1] && if spec_char.include? str[str.index(i) - 1]
                next
            else
                return false
            end
        end
    end

    return true
end

SimpleSymbols(STDIN.gets.chomp)
```

Comment: One problem is that you want to use `elsif`, not `else`.

Comment: You have 2 if statements on line 10

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two syntax errors in your code.

```
if spec_char.include? str[str.index(i) + 1] && if spec_char.include? str[str.index(i) - 1]
```

The line above contains two `if` statements. It should be:

```
if spec_char.include?(str[str.index(i) + 1]) && spec_char.include?( str[str.index(i) - 1])
```

Moreover the following line

```
else alpha.include? i
```

is incorrect as there is no `else` clause with condition. It should be

```
elsif alpha.include?(i)
```

Last but not least there are a few code conventions errors. You don't use `camelCase` in Ruby for method names, and you don't use explicit returns unless necessary.

```
def simple_symbols(str)
  spec_char = "+="
  alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

  str.each_char do |i|
    if spec_char.include?(i)
      next
    elsif alpha.include?(i)
      if spec_char.include?(str[str.index(i) + 1]) && spec_char.include?(str[str.index(i) - 1])
        next
      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end

  true
end

simple_symbols(STDIN.gets.chomp)
```

Comment: thank you so much. I have a lot to learn. Coming over from python has it's ups and downs. Thanks again.

Comment: ...and the name of the method.

Comment: It's not a camel-case convention issue. Method names cannot be constants.

Comment: @CarySwoveland In theory you can define a `SimpleSymbols` exactly as `uri` defines the `Kernel.URI` method (see https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/uri/common.rb#L705-L721)

Comment: I stand corrected. Here's something interesting: `def A; puts 'hi'; end; A #=> NameError: uninitialized constant A; A() #=> 'hi'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland correct. it will works if (and only if) called with explicit parenthesis (as you noticed).

Comment: @SimoneCarletti: Or an explicit receiver. (Or both, actually.)